SharePoint / Teams Date Column Restriction using Validation Syntax Question
I have two date columns in a SharePoint List. I am trying to figure out the proper syntax for use in the Validation box.
For the first, I want to restrict the date entered to only accept today's date or prior dates.
For the second, I would like to restrict the date entered to today's date and future dates.
Any syntax examples would be greatly appreciated.

For the first date column, you can use column validation like:
=[Date Column]<=Today()

For the second date column, you can use column validation like:
=[Date Column]>=Today()

Example:

Note:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).
Use correct display name of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
Wrap column names inside [] if your column name has space in it. For example: [My Column Name].


I enter "=[Last Updated Date] <= Today()" without the quotes save, go back in and look and it has been changed to =#NAME?<TODAY() and does not work. It seems like it does not recognize the column name. Any thoughts

Use correct "display name" of column. You can try adding column validation from classic experience column settings page as well. From List settings --> Columns section --> click on your column name, change the settings and save changes.
